# Iphone Orientation Change

Tags: iphone

I am trying to implement orientation change functionality in my application.I have overrided -(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation.

In this method i change the frame size of the tableview(including the position of the cell items) which is present in the view.
The tableview Details:

1. Added to the view as [self.view addSubView:tableView] in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller;
2. Cell item (row) has a textfield and a segmented control.
3. There are 10 cells in the table view and in landscape mode only 2 cells are visible and                    in potrait mode 5 cells are visible.

I have implemented scroller.

Issue:
Certain times on changing the orientation to potrait mode certain segmented controls in the cell are not rendered (Not shown at all).

This happens when i am viewing the last couple of cells in the landscape mode and i change the orientation to potrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a problem in your frame adjustment. I had a similar problem when i was rotating from portrait to landscape. Try to see if the logic behind the rotation process(settings frames, positions etc.) is correct. for me this article was really useful [link text](http://blog.sallarp.com/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation/)

for the tableView you could try to set the autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight to see if when rotating the table is adjusting correctly.

tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Answer (score 0):

My sandbox app
The solution is easy:

https://github.com/comonitos/programatical_device_orientation

in interface (h file) :

> BOOL rotated;

in implementation (m file):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return rotated;
}
- (void) setup 
{
   rotated = YES;
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
   rotated = NO;
}
```